# What’s the song playing in the background during Todoroki’s flashback of his fight against Izuku in season 3 episode 1 of My Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What’s the song playing in the background during Todoroki’s flashback of his fight against Izuku in season 3 episode 1 of My Hero Academia? Can’t seem to find the exact song. It’s around 14 minutes in episode 1 of season 3 right after Izuku says “It’s your quirk, not his”.

Answer (score 0):

This is ***Surpassing You*** (君を超えて, *Kimi wo Koete*), the 5th track from the 2nd disc of *My Hero Academia 2nd Original Soundtrack*.

YouTube link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aYjvc72T50&list=PLwhhprTdWbG494QOyVrMaSpYRa9NjKf4s&index=28